# How to merge file changes through git difftool

Tags: git, git-diff, git-difftool

I have another front end developer working with me who is just beginning in Javascript. I'd like to review his code for a while as he comes up to speed. Is it possible that as I merge his branch in that each file changed kicks out a call to difftool where I can see the changes, modify if needed, then continue on with the merge? I'm just looking for a workflow that is as seamless and quick as possible.

I'm using diffMerge as a tool, but also checking out Kaleidoscope.

Answer (score 0):

A tool to perform peer code-review is useful regardless how experienced you and your teammates are. So I would choose one of those tools, e.g. [reviewboard](https://www.reviewboard.org/), [gerrit](https://www.gerritcodereview.com/) or any other suitable to your taste. Efforts, spent on installation and exploring how they work ain't that great, but benefits are significant.

But if you don't want to bother yourself with 'special services', then you may stay with the approach used in Linux kernel development: a person willing to push his/her changes into upstream, prepares a series of commits, then generates a sequence of patches using [git format-patch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch), then sends them to an approving person (one may use [git send-email](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-send-email) but any other way to compose emails is perfect).

The approving person may review those patches in a text editor, or any other tool* and apply the patches within an editor or using [git apply](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply) or [git am](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-am)

* e.g. a lot of text-editors and IDEs has a designated mode to view and apply patches interactively.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on these tools. I'll check them out this evening when I have some time.